# Random initialization a struct

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

I defined two structs. Point and Triangle, I want to initialize them in main function with random values. But the compiler in this line has trouble and stops. what is the problem?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

struct Point{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
struct Triangle{
    Point* a;
    Point* b;
    Point* c;
};
int main() {
    Triangle t1;
    srand(time(0));
        t1.a->x=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5; //this line gives Segmentation fault
        t1.a->y=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.a->z=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.b->x=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.b->y=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.b->z=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.c->x=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.c->y=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
        t1.c->z=10.0*(rand()/RAND_MAX)-5;
}
```

Comment: Think about where `t1.a` is pointing. Show us the line where you initialize the `Point` it's pointing to.

Comment: What if you initialize it with non-random numbers?

Comment: By the way, the compiler has nothing to do with segmentation faults. A segmentation fault appears at runtime. But the compiler probably warns you that _"'t1.Triangle::a' is used uninitialized in this function"_ Or something like this. Pretty clear if you turn on warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're dereferencing uninitialised pointers, which has undefined behaviour.

There is no point in using pointers here - just use `Point`s as members.
This has several benefits:

- You don't need to worry about "the rule of whatever"; it Just Works
- You get to write less tedious book-keeping code, so you have more time to think about things that are less boring
- It's more than likely to be more efficient (dynamic allocation is slow)

Then add a couple of functions so you don't need to copy and paste so much:

```
struct Point{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Triangle{
    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;
};

double random_value()
{
    return (10.0*rand())/RAND_MAX - 5;
}

Point random_point()
{
    return { random_value(), random_value(), random_value() };
}

Triangle random_triangle()
{
    return { random_point(), random_point(), random_point() };
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    Triangle t1 = random_triangle();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the sensible way of doing this. (Do check the random element is sufficient for your requirements though.)

Comment: @Eric: I agree but it is difficult to convince folk of that. I think that one course of action is to downvote the accepted answer to signal to the community that it has defects and there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

## This code contains UB!

As mentioned in the comments, because the code you wrote requests the value pointed to by each pointer in the uninitialized `Triangle t1` struct, the compiler generated code that is undefined by the standard. This is known as **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR** because there is no sensible value to give the pointers by default. I would guess that if using a debugging configuration, the compiler would default initialize said pointers with the value of 0, which is an inaccessible address.

In order to fix this program, just initialize the value of t1, such that the member variables actually point to valid `Point`'s. These could be allocated on the stack or the heap, but it must be allocated.

Another thing to note is that you haven't seemed to given much thought for your question. For the future, I would try to test more on the problems you have, try to solve them on your own, and as a last resort, ask your question here on stack overflow. When asking a question, provide as much information as you can, especially information you found when trying to solve the problem on your own. Thanks ;)